# How many equalities /inequalities between indices

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out how to count the possibilities to arrange equalities and inequalities between some variables (in my case indeces of sums).

For example, $i,j,k$: then we have.
$$i=j=k=i \\
i=j\neq k \neq i \\
i \neq j=k\neq i  \\
$$

---

$$
i\neq j \neq k=i \\
i\neq j \neq k\neq i$$
These are 5 ways to arrange the signs. What bugs me is, that I can't figure out a way to count though I am not super familiar with combinatorics problems. I have separated the three possibilities where the first to signs basically already determine the last one from the two cases where this is not the case.

I would like to be able to know how many ways there are for $n$ variables. I know that for $n=4$, there are 15 but still. If this is a standard problem, a simple link to wikipedia etc. would be more than enough. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about partitions to subsets of equal variables:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number